# How to filter DeprecationWarnings that happen during importing?

Tags: python, django, logging, filtering, deprecation-warning

We are updating our application from Django 1.6 to 1.7.

We see a lot of these message:`RemovedInDjango18Warning`

Is there a way to filter them? They get emitted during importing.

We tried `warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', '...')` but the warnings get emitted before we call `warnings.filterwarnings()`.

How can I filter these warnings which happen during importing?

Comment: @Andy. I think this is a different question. I know how to use `warnings.filterwarnings()`. My problem is the timing: A lot of messages get emitted during importing. I don't know how to call warnings.filterwarnings() early enough

Comment: What about to [write your own filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/logging/#id5) in settings.py?

Comment: @danhip AFAIK the warnings get emitted before settings.py gets loaded. A filter in settings.py would be too late.

Comment: Look it here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30716923/842935

Comment: What WSGI server are you using. If you were using mod_wsgi then it can be achieved using a configuration directive in the Apache configuration file. See item 15 in features added in http://modwsgi.readthedocs.org/en/develop/release-notes/version-3.0.html

Comment: @GrahamDumpleton thank you very much for the link. This could solve some of the warnings. But we get the same warnings if we run cronjobs. Your solution is a work around. I think there is something not solved in the python world: Configuring logging. It is reimplemented over and over again. Python folks are programmers, they don't care for configuring an environment. Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29962525/configuring-the-logging-of-a-third-party-script

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Quickfix

To silence it only when you run `manage.py`, add these lines after `import sys`:

```
# ...
import sys

if not sys.warnoptions:
    sys.warnoptions += [None]

# ...
```

If you also want to silence it from your WSGI server (i.e. Apache), update `your_project/wsgi.py` and add the following lines after `import os`:

```
# ...
import os
import sys

if not sys.warnoptions:
    sys.warnoptions += [None]

# ...
```

---

## Explanation

The reason this works is because of how `django.utils.log.configure_logging()` handles it:

```
def configure_logging(logging_config, logging_settings):
    if not sys.warnoptions:
        # Route warnings through python logging
        logging.captureWarnings(True)
        # RemovedInNextVersionWarning is a subclass of DeprecationWarning which
        # is hidden by default, hence we force the "default" behavior
        warnings.simplefilter("default", RemovedInNextVersionWarning)
    # ...
```

It's deliberately called early in the boot process as part of `django.setup()`, which explains why errors were emitted before you were able to silence them further down the stack.

Adding a new element to `sys.warnoptions` forces it to evaluate to `True`, bypassing the logic. This is harmless since it's [only used during python startup](https://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html#the-warnings-filter) when loaded by the `warnings` module.

`RemovedInNextVersionWarning` is just an alias for [`RemovedInDjango18Warning` in Django 1.7](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.7.x/django/utils/deprecation.py#L13). It is set to [`RemovedInDjango19Warning` in 1.8](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.8.x/django/utils/deprecation.py#L16), and so on for future versions -- this code should be future proof for this type of `DeprecationWarning`.

---

## Command line methods

Note that `sys.warnoptions` is normally set during python startup based on the [`-W` argument](https://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-W) when calling python. Therefore, a simple way to just silence the warnings when you use the dev server is `python -W123 manage.py runserver`. This requires no modification of files, but does result in a single harmless warning at startup since `123` is just a placeholder and not a valid warning action.

Another way is `python -Wi::DeprecationWarning manage.py runserver`, though this will ignore **ALL** `DeprecationWarning`s, including possibly ones of interest which are not `RemovedInDjango18Warning`.